# Bootstrap 3 column gutter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to fix this problem multiple times but it still occurs, I just can't find the right fix.
I cannot create gutter around columns in Bootstrap 3. Here's my Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/creuxttL

My exact problem: When I create these three columns, I expect some gutter to be between them, so they don't look like one big brick. I don't get any gutter by default, so I tried to do it manually - with css class `.col` . I still don't get any margin/padding around the boxes. What should I do?

Comment: Your row should be `class="row"` not `id="row"`

Comment: Still doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: Then you need to define your problem more clearly.

Comment: I edited my original post. Go check it out.

Comment: But there is a gutter, Bootstrap has 15px on each side of `col-*`

Comment: The bootstrap gutter is in the padding, not in the margin.

Comment: @Gasper.. Your code is working perfectly fine. Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/creuxttL/1/ . You missed `bootstrap.css` file (bootstrap styling file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fiddle does not have bootstrap 3 included. http://jsfiddle.net/va94exo2/ is a slight modification.

Have wrapped all of your col-md-4 content with an inner div and changed the ID="row" to class and removed your extra .col class, have also then styled the inner div.

```css
.inner-content{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00b9ff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.overlay-pic {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #44cbff;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlay p {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.col {
  /*gutter*/
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.col:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="inner-content">    
      
      <h1>Festival 2001</h1>
      <img src="event.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Our event.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <h1>Who are we?</h1>
      <img src="question.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Read more about us</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <h1>where, when?</h1>
      <img src="calendar.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Look at our calendar.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not positive this is *exactly* what you're looking for but if you just want space between the rows you can add a "margin-top" attribute to your css in the ".col-md-4" class.

Hope this helps.

```css
.col-md-4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00b9ff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.overlay-pic {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #44cbff;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlay p {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.col {
  /*gutter*/
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.col:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col">
      <h1>Festival 2001</h1>
      <img src="event.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Our event.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col">
      <h1>Who are we?</h1>
      <img src="question.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Read more about us</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col">
      <h1>where, when?</h1>
      <img src="calendar.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Look at our calendar.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see columns(vertical), only three div "blocks" stacked on top of each other.  Did you try running the code snippet I provided?  I've added some space between each div / "block"..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is not added. I modified your code. And I hope you are expecting this.

```css
.col {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.overlay-pic {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #44cbff;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlay p {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.col h1{
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col">
    <div style="margin:5px; background:#00b9ff;border: 1px solid black;">
      <h1>Festival 2001</h1>
      <img src="event.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Our event.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col">
    <div style="margin:5px; background:#00b9ff;border: 1px solid black;">
      <h1>Who are we?</h1>
      <img src="question.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Read more about us</p>
        </div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col">
    <div style="margin:5px; background:#00b9ff;border: 1px solid black;">
      <h1>where, when?</h1>
      <img src="calendar.jpg" class="overlay-pic hidden-tablet img-responsive">
      <div class="overlay">
        <p>Look at our calendar.</p>
      </div>
      </div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```